# Is there a way to measure systemic risk in a country, and if so which countries have the highest level of systemic risk?

Tags: finance, financial-crisis

> The risk of counterparty default or counterparty credit risk rises to
> the level of systemic risk in three scenarios. First, **systemic risk
> arises when the failure of a market participant with a robust
> derivatives portfolio could trigger large unexpected losses on its
> derivatives trades; the losses could seriously impair the financial
> condition of one or more of its counterparties.** 13 Second, the fear of
> a market participant’s failure could create systemic risk if
> counterparties try to reduce exposure to the large, weak market
> participant to avoid potential loss- es. 14

http://www.stanfordlawreview.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/05/Allen-64-Stan-L-Rev-1079.pdf

Is there a way to measure systemic risk in a country, and if so which countries have the highest level of systemic risk? By systemic risk, I mean financial risk from derivatives, is there a way to measure the level of systemic risk in a country and determine which countries suffer from the highest systemic risk? My opinion is that it would probably be either the United States or some Western country, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: It's called a credit rating. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_credit_rating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type "measuring systemic financial risk" into Google Scholar you will unsurprisingly see a rather extensive economic literature on the topic. So regarding the first half of the headline question, yes, of course there are ways to try and measure this, but like other economic measures (e.g. GDP, unemployment but perhaps even more so), it's not an especially simple thing to do.

VLab at the NYU Stern School has [data](https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/srisk) that puts out a dollar amount per country. China shows up at #1 by far. US is #2 with Japan close behind.

Comment: But that's volatility analysis, I don't get anything for systemic risk.

Comment: @Sayaman No. The NYU Stern data [measuring SRISK](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1611229) is not measuring volatility.